# Rails - Using Paperclip to temporarily store files and then move to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

How is this possible to do?

When a user upload files, I want to upload the file to an AttachmentTemp model using paperclip, and use some type of temp folder on S3.

Then in my delayed job, use that temp file, but save that file to the Attachment model paperclip where it can be processed via delayed_job.

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but how about the following?

First, run the Paperclip generator for both models, so both tables have the necessary columns in the database (post migration).

Then use the Temp model in your user-facing new action/view.

Later, in your delayed job, load up each AttachmentTemp instance (filtered on some status criterion) and copy each one to an Attachment instance. So you're just translating one to the other.

In your remaining user-facing actions, use Attachment instances (so AttachmentTemps are only used when first creating a record).

Comment: Thanks, how do I copy from attachmentTemp to Attachment? Attachment Temp would be the orig file only, no processing. So I'd want to copy it to Attachments in a way that paperclip processed it for image sizes etcc., thumbnails etc...

Comment: You can access the model's attributes and methods just like from a controller (or try to do something more clever and Ruby-like, but the basic approach should work). So instead of creating an Attachment from params, copy the attributes from AttachmentTemp. Configure Attachment with styles (image sizes), but don't add styles to AttachmentTemp because you don't need them. When you save Attachment it should create the processed images you specified, just like when saving from a controller method.