# how to store image in file system Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, database-design, paperclip

Two models.

Assets  - used to upload files with paperclip.

```
class AddAttachmentsPhotoToAsset < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :assets, :photo_file_name, :string
    add_column :assets, :photo_content_type, :string
    add_column :assets, :photo_file_size, :integer
    add_column :assets, :photo_updated_at, :datetime
  end
```

Boards - a blog

```
class CreateBoards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :boards, :options => "AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000" do |t|
        t.column :deliver_on,    :datetime
        t.column :time_zone,     :string
      t.column :header_text,   :text
      t.column :name,          :string
      t.column :age,           :int, :default => "0"
      t.column :template_id,   :int, :default => "1", :null => false
      t.column :photo, :string
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

new.html.erb

There is an ajax iframe work around at the bottom of this form. The user can upload a picture and view it on the form before submitting it. Therefore there is no board that can be saved to upload the picture with. So I had to create the asset object.

```
<% form_tag(action, :id => "form")  do %>
<%=image_tag board_image, :width => 140, :height => 166, :id => 'user_image' %><%= hidden_field :board, :photo, :id => 'image_name'%>

<%= error_messages_for :user,:board,  :header_message => "" %>
<%= label_tag  :name, "Friend's Name:", :class => "large"%>
<%= text_field :board, "name", :class => "large", :style => Board::NAME_WIDTH %>    
.
.
.
<%=submit_tag "#{button_text}", :id => "board_submit"%> 
<% end %>
```

This has to be outside of the other form or it won't work so I have it here at the bottom after the <% end %> tag of the other form.

iframe ajax style file upload of a picture.

```
<% remote_form_for(:asset, :url => { :controller => "asset", :action => "upload", :id => @tmp_id }, :html => { :method => :post, :id => 'uploadForm', :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :photo, :class => 'file' %>
<% end %>
```

upload.js

```
//ajax file upload
        $(function() { 
        $("#uploadForm input").change(function(){
         $("#uploadForm").ajaxSubmit({
          beforeSubmit: function(a,f,o) {
           o.dataType = "json";
          },
          complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
          $('#user_image').attr('src', XMLHttpRequest.responseText +'?'+ new Date().getTime());
          $('#image_name').attr('value', XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
           return; false;
          },
         });
        });
        });
```

In assets_controller.rb

```
 def upload
      if params_posted?(:asset) #check that the form was submitted with a post action
        @asset = Asset.new(params[:asset]) #create  new paperclip object to upload item
        @asset.save   #upload the photo
        render :text => @asset.photo.url #put the name on the form.
      end 
  end
```

In board_controller

```
def create
...
@board.new(params[:board])
...


end
```

File gets uploaded with **assets** object.
File is stored in **assets** table in database
photo url is stored in the hidden field on the form.
Board is created and photo url is stored in the Boards table.

Thus I have stored photo data in two tables which does not seem correct.

I am a newbie, green as there ever was.

Is it better to store the asset.id of the Asset instance used to upload the images instead of the image url into the Board table?

To be clearer:

Should I have a field in my Boards table

```
t.column asset_id
```

and then access the assets photo data someway?

Thanks immensley in advance for your expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871438/rails-using-paperclip-to-temporarily-store-files-and-then-move-to-another-model)

When I transfer the information from the @asset object to the board object.

In Board.rb I do as corroded suggested and add the paperclip item

```
 has_attached_file :photo  #I can also add styles, where I want to save the photo etc
```

So I don't think I need the boards photo from params. I create it from the url of the @asset.photo.url.

```
   @board.photo = @asset.photo
```

When I do @board.save it will trigger all of the paperclip methods as if the file was being uploaded because they get triggered when the items are saved.  So they will be copied from the temp location to where I want them to reside when I have a board.  I then have to delete out the temp directories and the assest in the assets table as its done its job.

Update: It is all working perfectly now. I have corrected the code above.

important note!!!!!

you must do the following after you save the new model or the url and path values will be wrong.

model.photo.reprocess!

(replace model with your model.In my case it was @board.photo.reprocess!)

That is my final answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually, why not just connect the attachments to your board model instead of having two separate models for them? are you using the assets for your other models? If not, it is better to just put the has_attachment in your board.rb model

Comment: Thanks corroded. I would like to do that. The problem is I am uploading the photo before the form gets saved so the user can see the image on the form. I can't use a board object to save them because that would require me to save the board to upload the images. The board won't save because it is missing required data such as a name or email address.  That is as far as I can see or am I wrong?

Comment: The association would be: Board belongs_to :asset     Asset has_one :board. That sounds very strange to me. That is why I don't think its correct. How can I create a association between the Board and Asset that makes sense.

Comment: Board has_one :asset and Asset belongs_to :board. that is more logical right? since it is the board that has the asset

Comment: I see what you mean though, about uploading the photo to the form before you save it. if you REALLY have to do it that way(although it seems a bit bad habit, since a user can just quit half way and youll have orphaned assets...) what you can do is create the Board model when you get to /new. you'll have to create a rake task to delete unfinished forms though